# How to route subfolder files in PHP

Tags: php, url, routes, subdirectory

I have the below folder structure

```
Template        *Header and Footer here
admisions
--/bs.php
--/master.php
--/MS.php
Administration
--/Facult.php
--/Office Staff.php
--/Project Staff.php

index.php
```

So I want the URL to look like: `mysite.com/admisions/bs`

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: That depends on your web server.
Apache or Nginx?

Either way, you can create a file "admisions/bs/index.php" and it's URL would be admisions/bs/

Comment: Apache @DannyZB

Comment: i want the URL structure like  mysite.com/admisions/bs     @MattS

Comment: 1. you can create a file "admisions/bs/index.php" and it's URL would be admisions/bs/

The server automatically serves the index.php script in every folder when installed. the URL of the folder opens that script.

2. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html
if you want to map a URL to a different folder

Is either of those what you are looking for?

Comment: do you want to create an index fie for every sub-directory or are you wanting to just format the url? take a look at <a href="http://www.htaccess-guide.com/">httaccess</a>

Comment: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/   i dont know why it printed like that in my last comment sorry

Comment: Ok.. i am trying. then will share with you.

Comment: ok i have define a BASE_URL. Now it's working fine.